# ASP.NET MVC Session timeout handling in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How to redirect program flow to a controller action. I would like to simulate MVC’s RedirectToAction(“ActionName”, “ControllerName”,  route values) call inside Global.asax.cs. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using MVC 3, I'd recommend [writing your own](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/03/21/ActionFilterAttributeExamplesASPNETMVCFrameworkPreview2.aspx) [actionfilter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs), which you can then [apply globally](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx).

A small code example:

```
public class HandleSessionTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(FilterExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Do whatever it is you want to do here.
        // The controller and request contexts, along with a whole lot of other
        // stuff, is available on the filter context.
    }
}
```

And then in your `Global.asax.cs:`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Register global filter
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleSessionTimeoutAttribute());

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is what I need. Will try it out in a bit and mark this as an answer